# Where can I store outdoor patio or deck furniture over the winter?

Tags: deck, furniture, patio, winterizing, winter

I have a variety of plastic / wood / metal patio furniture that I am looking to store over the winter.
Unfortunately, I don't have space inside to store it. 
We usually see temperatures of about 10 degrees below freezing during the winter.

What is the best way to store it?

Comment: throw a tarp over it?

Comment: Doesn't moisture build up underneath the tarp?

Comment: it's a trade off. But during the winter, the air is extremely dry, so very little moisture in the air. Take the tarp off after snow melt.

Comment: Presumably that's -10 degrees C, not 22 degrees F.

Comment: Do you have any [self-storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-storage) facilities in your area?  If so, you could rent a storage area for the winter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no space in a garage or shed (like me) then outside is your only option. I use a 20'x20' plastic tarp tied around my four patio chairs and table on my deck. They've survived 6 Minnesota winters. After a **big** snowfall, sometimes I'll sweep the snow off if it accumulates.

Comment: Do you have the furniture completely wrapped? or is the bottom side uncovered for air circulation?

Comment: The bottom is uncovered, I tie the four sides of the tarp to the deck. Though my deck is fairly exposed, so I'm careful to tie the tarp tightly hoping a big gust of wind won't blow it away.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's extremely important to take note what material your lawn and garden furniture are before considering what kind of storage you need. Some type of material, like wood especially because its susceptible to mould and rot, needs to be properly treated before you bunker things down into a storage unit somewhere. Then there are also self storage options where you don't have to clutter your own garage or attic with the items for half the year when it's cold too.

Answer (score 0):

For the last 10 years or so, we've covered our outdoor furniture on our patio.  First we removed all of the cushions and put them in contractor garbage bags, not closed to allow for air flow, and placed them on top of our riding lawnmower in the shed.  In other words, they are off of the floor.

Then, we group the furniture together, making sure there is a peak in the middle, think teepee.  The grouping is about 4' tall.  The chair/sofa covers remain on the pieces.  Then we cover with a 20' x 20' outdoor tarp.  We chose a dark green, almost black, one.  Run a piece of rope in and out (weaving from the outside of one, into the inside of the next) all the way around the bottom of the furniture pile.  Cinch the rope and tie in a knot.   Tuck under the excess to keep leaves from entering underneath.  The air flow comes from underneath, as well.  It has worked wonderfully for us.  If there is snow that accumulates on the top, we simply brush it off with a broom, occasionally.  Make sure to uncover as soon as the snow melts to avoid any undue mold, etc.  Besides, you'll be ready for spring at that point!  Enjoy, and Happy Holidays!